# Outlook exchange more details on lockout

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I work in an entreprise which uses Outlook exchange servers and Outlook 2010 up to 2016. One of my biggest issues I got is the fact when a user is locked out in Active directory (because he tried to many times, happens each monday :(  ) he gets in Outlook and the only thing is gets is a small credentials window and he has to type the password again. He does it around 10 times, gets sick, call the IT Support (me ) and I unlock the account.

It's surprising to me that Outlook exchange or Outlook 2010 doesnt say "your account on active directory is locked, please call IT" instead of just prompting for your password. Is there a way to tell it that or give it more information in some way ?

Comment: I don't know of such notification, but perhaps you could shorten the Account lockout duration.

Comment: @harrymc shorten the account duration wont fix my issue with the prompt popping up asking for credential when the account is locked. thats the issue, not the time. I would assume if the account is locked, then tell the user on Outlook "your account on AD is locked". But outlook just gives the popup with username/password again and again

Comment: Are they locking their account while trying to login? If so, how are they then getting in to run outlook in the first place?

Comment: @smock when you're in a AD environment, your computer (windows) can keep your account locally on your computer so if you have a laptop and you,re on the move, you can log in the "domain" without being connected. This is a normal behavior to some extent.

Also some people just lock their accounts, they don't unlog from it.

Comment: @FluffyDestroyer So is that how this particular user is locking their account? You would still need to get your password correct to login with cached credentials. Are they just sitting there, disconnected, trying password after password until they get the right one? How are they locking their account in the first place? (I know we have a lot of issues when people change their passwords and they have it saved on their phones for WiFi etc)

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic tells us "What topics can I ask about here?  Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …and it is not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,"